# Changing Console Window's size throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, console, size, console-application

I am trying to set the size of the Console Window in a c# console application. I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with this message:

> The value must be less than the console's current maximum window size
>   of 41 in that dimension. Note that this value depends on screen
>   resolution and the console font.

I am using this to set it:

```
Console.WindowHeight = 480;
```

How do you set the Console window's size properly?

Comment: Console height is specified in rows (lines), not pixels.

Comment: That was the problem. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From *MSDN* of [`Console.WindowHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowheight.aspx) property:

> The height of the console window measured in rows.

As you can see, these are not *pixels*. Just remember, these values can change depending on your screen resolution and the console font. You can find maximum *height* and *width* values with [`Console.LargestWindowWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.largestwindowwidth.aspx) and [`Console.LargestWindowHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.largestwindowheight.aspx) properties.

```
Console.WriteLine(Console.LargestWindowHeight);
Console.WriteLine(Console.LargestWindowWidth);
```

Comment: Just noticed this more detailed answer. Changed it to the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

Console height is specified in rows (lines), not pixels.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowheight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recently published some information around this, see:

1. [Understanding Windows Console Host Settings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/)

Try this in powershell:

```bsh
$windowSize = $(get-item hkcu:\console).GetValue("WindowSize")
$windowHeight = $windowSize -shr 16
$windowWidth = ($windowSize -shl 16) -shr 16
```

Answer (score 0):

When I set the Window width to say 130, and when I click the maximise button in Console App, the Console window width is not chnanging in the console application.
Can anyone please check and confirm ?

```
if (Console.WindowWidth == Console.LargestWindowWidth || Console.WindowWidth == Console.LargestWindowHeight) 
{ 
    Console.WindowWidth = 130;
    Console.WindowHeight = 30;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please post this as your own question, with a link to this question here, to notify that it's related. Good tips in [ask], [answer] and [tour]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35687073)

Answer (score -4):

you can set a windowHeight less than 62, if u try exceed this value error throw the system.

```
class Pro
{
    public static void fun()
    {
        Console.WindowHeight = 61;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to asp .net ");
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pro.fun();
    }

    // Summary:
    //     Gets the largest possible number of console window rows, based on the current
    //     font and screen resolution.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The height of the largest possible console window measured in rows.
    public static int LargestWindowHeight { get; }

    // Summary:
    //     Gets the largest possible number of console window columns, based on the
    //     current font and screen resolution.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The width of the largest possible console window measured in columns.
    public static int LargestWindowWidth { get; }
```

The above information catch Console[from metadata].

Comment: _U_ can with _u'r_ font and display settings.  The rest of us are better off checking the `LargestWindowHeight` property.

Comment: As Habo says; this is only the max value for *you*. The actual maximum value will depend on every person's screen size. Not just the programmer's screen size/res - but the end-user's. Also, you don't even explain at all *why* it has to be less than 62; What does "62" mean in this context? (*I* know the answer - but your answer does not say)