# How can I set a minimum console size C#?

Tags: c#, console-application

How can I set a minimum console size in console application C# that users can not change? Thank you in advance for answers ;)

Comment: You can't. A console application doesn't have any control over its host.

Comment: what have you tried, consider https://stackoverflow.com/q/15099523/1132334

Comment: you can set the [console size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setwindowsize(v=vs.110).aspx), but you cannot set the minimum size

Comment: The user is in control over his console, your program is merely the humble visitor.  Give them a good reason to not to want to make it smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any resize Event for Console. But as a workaround you can try (not recommended!):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int MinHeight = 10;
    const int MinWidth = 10;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.WindowHeight > MinHeight || Console.WindowWidth > MinWidth)
            {
                Console.SetWindowSize(MinWidth, MinHeight);
            }
        }
    });
    //  Do some work here
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: would this not cause 100% cpu on one core?

Comment: of course, infinity loop. But as a workaround why not :) And the asnwer is: There aren't any resize Event for Console

Comment: well we [could do lots of stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880337/1132334) with [this handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1277609/1132334). but we should not.

Comment: Also doesn't your solution set the max height of the console, it should resize when the console height or width falls below the given min and max values not when it exceeds them.